# Is drinking tap water safe in Île-de-France on a long term?

Tags: water, lasting-effects-duration, kidney-stones, metal, kidney-disease

I work in [Île-de-France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Ele-de-France) (a region in France mainland), Orsay to be precise. 
I would be here atleast for 2 years.
Should I be concerned of the long term health issues by drinking 
tap water on a regular basis?
My concern mainly roots from discussion with my colleagues (they are not medical professionals) that tap water contains more mineral concentration and may lead to kidney stone in the future.